# What's wrong with my regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'm expecting a string NOT to match a regular expression, but it is!

```
>>> re.compile('^P|([LA]E?)$').match('PE').group()
'P'
```

This seems like a bug, because I see no way for the $ to match. On the other hand, it seems unlikely that Python's re lib would not be able to handle this simple case. Am I missing something here?

btw, Python prints this out when I start it:

> Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two other points worth mentioning: `^` is redundant when you use `re.match()`, and if you want to match the end of the string, use r`"\Z"`, not `"$".`

**Why $ is evil:** Suppose we want to check that the whole of some string `s` matches some pattern `foo`. We don't want to call it a match if there is anything after the pattern. Let's see what happens if there is a newline after the pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo\n'
>>> re.match('foo$', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00BAFE90> # match -- FAIL!
>>> re.match('foo\Z', s) # no match -- OK
>>>
```

Here are excerpts from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

Docs for `$`: *Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string ...* this is using the **default** modes, and is nothing to do with MULTILINE mode.

Docs for `\Z`: *Matches only at the end of the string*. Nothing to do with modes, and not spooked by newlines.

Comment: What is \Z? I'm pretty sure $ matches the end of the string (unless you're using re.MULTILINE)

Comment: OOh! Thanks! Yes, $ seems very evil now that I know this. On the other hand, I believe most people know $, making it more readable than \Z :/

Answer (score 4):

```
^P|([LA]E?)$
```

becomes

```
^P
|
([LA]E?)$
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm guessing it parses this way, because ^ and $ are treated like regular characters. Is that right?

Comment: They're treated like anything else in an expression aside from the `|` character, which has a very low grouping priority.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote "P or ([LA]E?)". "P" matches.

If you meant for the anchors to apply to both cases, then perhaps you meant this:

^(?:P|([LA]E?))$

Answer (score 1):

It will match either `^P` or `([LA]E)$`. Did you mean `^(?:P|([LA]E?))$` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It prints the same output on Mac OS X and on Linux(Debian testing).  I would be surprised to see a bug behave the same on three major platforms.  Besides, 'PE' has 'P' in the beginning, so I don't see a problem in it matching the regex.  Similarly, 'AE' matches the regex too.  On both Debian and on Mac OS X.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's that the regex as written is not what the asker intended.